# Epub file not turning pages on nook devices

Tags: creation, nook, epub, production

OK, I'm having a very strange problem with a reflowable epub file I'm creating. It displays fine on most reading systems, but on the Nook, it will not advance pages across chapter breaks. Instead, it just hangs or sometimes does half a page change (to the point that I can see some of the text from the next chapter), then slides back.

### About the Book

- Reflowable
- Epub 3.0
- contains images, mostly around 75kb - 150kb in size, no larger than 800px on the long side
- highly formatted (lots of elements and classes)

### Things I've tried

- Removed all CSS: It looks like it must be an HTML problem
- Removed all instances of more than one class definition per element (like `class="class1 class2"`)
- Other epub 3.0 books work just fine on this same device (and have for years), so it's not that.

I recognize that it's tough to say without looking at the code, but I can't post the book online--it's not my intellectual property. I've had the nook do similar things with background images, but with the CSS not being an issue (I made a test version of the file with a blank CSS file), it's not that. If anyone's had experiences with files on the Nook that sound remotely similar, I'd love to hear about them.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify if it is the code, or the book content that is not your intellectual property to share? If the code is yours, you should be able to strip out the text of the book and replace with TextTextText for posting and problem solving.  Of course you may stumble across the problem while stripping out the text, and validating the error still exist, in which case you will have a chance to answer your own question.

Comment: "Chapters" are often single XHTML files inside the EPUB. if your Nook is old, and doesn't have enough memory for a HUGE chapter (XHTML file), the device may take a few minutes to display the first page of the "chapter", or it may lock up entirely. So how old is your Nook, how much memory does it have, and how long is the chapter (in kilobytes) inside the EPUB you are trying to open that doesn't open? To see inside the epub, copy it to a zip file. Ex: `copy myfile.epub myfile.zip`. Now use your OS to look inside the zip file and find the XHTML file that contains your chapter that locks up.